# How to get index from Column, Row

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I made a `customGirdView` like below, everything as I expected, but I want to make an event when I click an item, I cannot get the `index` of each item, it always toasts the last value of `index`:

```
customGirdView(List<SuggestionsProductModel> data) {
    List<Widget> widgets = List<Widget>();

    int index = 0;

    while (index < data.length) {
      widgets.add(Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          /*item 1*/
          Expanded(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: 'Clicked to ' + index.toString(),
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIos: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0);
              },
              child:Center()),
            ),
          ),
          /*item 2*/
          Expanded(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: 'Clicked to ' + (index + 1).toString(),
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIos: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0);
              },
              child: Center(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));
      index += 2;
    }

    return Column(
      children: widgets,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `ListView.builder`? See doc here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

```dart
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 2,
    itemBuilder: (context, snapshot){
      Expanded(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: 'Clicked to ' + (index).toString(),
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIos: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0);
              },
              child: Center(),
            ),
          ),
    },
)
```

You wouldn't need to specify your `msg` as index, index + 1, index + 2, etc... just refer to `index` and it goes through the list. Optionally, remove the `itemCount` to make it infinitely long.
You can also add

```
if(index > x){
return null;
}
```

to stop the list at any given index.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Do not use ListView

Comment: Any reason for that?

Answer (score -2):

Index can be added and can get for child widget as mentioned in the below article. The articale is written by my self. Assuming that the inforamtion is more relevant here.

[Indexed Column and indexed Row](https://medium.com/@raghumudem/indexed-column-indexed-row-in-flutter-program-e0df124d6ef9)